# Oracle merge - unable to get stable set of rows after deleting duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query to merge data from the individuals2 table.  I still get the "unable to get a stable set of rows" error after deleting all the `full_name` duplicates in individuals2.  What am I missing?

```
MERGE INTO TBLHISTORYPERSON h
USING individuals2 i
    ON (lower(i.FULL_NAME) = lower(h.FULL_NAME) AND 
        i.DOB = h.hDOB)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET h.PERSON_ID = i.PERSON_ID
WHERE h.PERSON_ID IS null
```

Comment: You have to real dulicates, but the `lower(FULL_NAME)` are dups. E.g. `Max` and `max`

Comment: Hi @MarmiteBomber.  I don't understand what you're saying.  Can you rephrase please?

Comment: `Max` does not equal `max` i.e. no duplicate, but you use `lower(h.FULL_NAME)` and that makes the string equal, i.e. duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be in the `lower(FULL_NAME)`expression in the join condition.

It is not enough that `FULL_NAME` and `DOB` are unique in the table `individuals2`.

`lower(FULL_NAME)` and `DOB` *must be unique*

A small example

```
create table TBLHISTORYPERSON
(FULL_NAME varchar2(10),
hdob int,
person_id int);

insert into TBLHISTORYPERSON (FULL_NAME, hdob, person_id)
values ('Max',1,null);

create table individuals2
(FULL_NAME varchar2(10),
dob int,
person_id int);

insert into individuals2 (FULL_NAME, dob, person_id)
values ('Max',1,2);
insert into individuals2 (FULL_NAME, dob, person_id)
values ('max',1,3);


MERGE INTO TBLHISTORYPERSON h
USING individuals2 i
    ON (lower(i.FULL_NAME) = lower(h.FULL_NAME) AND 
        i.DOB = h.hDOB)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET h.PERSON_ID = i.PERSON_ID
WHERE h.PERSON_ID IS null
;

ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
```

Remove one of the rows and it works

```
delete from individuals2 where full_name = 'Max';

1 row deleted.


The MERGE works

1 row merged.

Select * from TBLHISTORYPERSON;

FULL_NAME        HDOB  PERSON_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
Max                 1          3
```

Comment: Thank you.  I removed "lower" and it worked!

Comment: Yes @belmer01 this is an alternative solution. You must decide if you merge your customers case *sensitive* or not. Good luck!